# KWrite installation/ usage errors

Tags: fedora, kde-plasma

I used to be able to use KWrite in the Fedora terminal fine, a few permission issues raised but weren't too problematic. However, I have been unable to open KWrite, although I can run scripts written in it fine. Whenever I try to open KWrite, I am given the message:

> Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported "Session bus not found
>
> To circumvent this problem try the following command (with Linux and bash)
>
> `export $(dbus-launch)`"

This command does not seem to do anything helpful. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please add more details? How are you trying to open KWrite? Have you done a Google search already?

Comment: I tried to open it using the command "kwrite" or "KWrite", which worked fine earlier but no longer. I have done google searches but nothing seems to work, or I don't understand what the sites are referring to, regards terminology or fix.